# Cron jobs on IBM i 7.1

Tags: cron, crontab, aix, ibm-server

I just found out today that on an IBM i system I am able to use SSH to get to a Unix-like terminal (AIX/PASE) and would like to use this to schedule automated tasks using crontab.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I know in Linux just creating the crontab file is enough, but what about AIX on IBM i?

Answer (score 2):

IBM [AIX 5.3 has a crontab command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/crontab.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-2-149) which allows you to submit, edit, list, and removes cron jobs.

If you are the root user, you can use the crontab feature. If you do not have root access, your login has to be added to the `cron.allow` file and at the same time not in `cron.deny`. The `cron.allow` and `cron.deny` files are located under the `/var/adm/cron` directory.

Comment: None of those directories exist on our IBM i and crontab isn't a command.  I was hoping just editing the cron file would be enough but it's not.  I'm beginning to think that since IBM i has its own built-in job scheduler they didn't bother to port crontab.  It's just a pain to have to ask the RPG devs to schedule jobs to call php functions I write.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaKR - We have the same inefficiencies at work as well. Hopefully, it is just a one time change or minimal changes once scheduled. Good luck!